# What is this magical "ih" variable in the initialization of this python program?

Tags: python, initialization

In attempting to learn a bit about curses, I ran across [this example of using curses in python.](https://github.com/LyleScott/Python-curses-Scrolling-Example/blob/master/curses_scrolling.py) I understand all of what's going on, except for the very last couple of lines:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ih = MenuDemo()
```

Specifically, what is that "ih" and how does it relate to the initialization of the python program?

Some additional details: I did just try renaming the `ih` variable, and I found that it's name has nothing to do with behaviour. That leads me to assume that this is general python-related behaviour.

Though I do have some experience building things with python, I guess I missed this section of the book. Can someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is absolutely *nothing* magic about the name `ih`. It is *just* a name. In this specific example, the name is not used, redundant, and can be removed altogether.

A class called `MenuDemo` is called, and the result of that call, an instance of the class, is stored in the name `ih`. Or it would be if it wasn't for the fact that instantiating the class triggers an infinite loop.

Creating an instance means the class `.__init__()` method is invoked, which does:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.screen = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    self.screen.keypad(1) 
    self.screen.border(0)
    self.topLineNum = 0
    self.highlightLineNum = 0
    self.markedLineNums = []
    self.getOutputLines()
    self.run()
```

So this instance creates a Curses screen, changes a few settings, sets a few instance attributes and calls to methods on the instance, `.getOutputLines()` and `.run()`.

The `.run()` method does all the work, looping endlessly. It never returns (rather, it calls `self.exit()` at some point, which doesn't actually exist so that'd raise an exception).

As a result, the `__init__()` method never returns either, and thus the `MenuDemo()` call never returns and nothing is ever assigned to `ih`.

You could completely *remove* the `ih =` part and not change the functionality of the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MenuDemo()
```

Not having `ih =` there would at least remove the confusion.